# "cannot read the Linux header." New install, old machine

Tags: ubuntu, installation, grub

This *could* be a hardware problem. I hope not. I have an old Compaq Evo laptop and I have completed the install of lubuntu from here: http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/11.10/release/.
There were no complaints during setup which was a complete wipe of the 250 GB HD. I get a boot menu when booting from the HD but it has never got past the error message:

```
error: cannot read the Linux header.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I am now in rescue mode and I can execute a shell in /dev/sda1. When I do fdisk -l I see just three partitions:

- /dev/sda1 (id:83), real big
- /dev/sda2 (id:5), extended
- /dev/sda5 (id:82), swap

I can see files in /boot and in my home directory. What to do next? (and by the way you're not allowed say "bring laptop to recycling centre").

Here are the errors from my RESULTS.txt

```
unlzma: Decoder error
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

I wonder is it because the boot files are in a part of the disk that is inaccessible to the BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
The single large partition for / was causing a problem. I assume because of the old BIOS. I solved it by manually partitioning as follows:

```
40 GB  / 
 2 GB  /boot 
 1 GB  /swap
```

There she boots.