# After a partial update of Ubuntu 12.04LTS, the system is now un-bootable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I just upgraded to version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything was fine until the restart and entered the grub.  I give the first option to enter the menu and I get a screen with two errors that would be these:

- error: cannot read the Linux headers
- error: you need to load the kernel first

From there it returns to the menu and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano now that we've got it translated to English, this question is appropriate for here.  Not every Ubuntu/Mac/etc. question needs to be migrated.  See [When should questions be moved to AskDifferent/AskUbuntu/…?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4394/when-should-questions-be-moved-to-askdifferent-askubuntu)

Comment: Related: [“cannot read the Linux header.” New install, old machine](http://superuser.com/questions/381539/cannot-read-the-linux-header-new-install-old-machine)

Answer (score 1):

In the menu it drops you back to, it should have a prompt underneath that says "Hit e to edit before boot".

Hit that, and then on the next page you should see the grub commands, make sure the kernel is above the initrd.  Something like:

```
set root=(hd0,1)             #Just leave this one for now
linux /boot/vmlinuz          # This should be here, initrd should be below it.
initrd /boot/initrd.img
```

After that, I think you hit escape and B or something (a prompt should show you).

Let us know if your grub menu already looks that way.